# Angular Material - mat-table not rendering data from rest api

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, angular-material, angular7

I've been trying to implement [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) table example from Angular Material without luck

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, the data which is being provided by my REST endpoint is clearly visible on the console output.

My suspicions are that maybe the data isn't quite loaded yet, when the table is rendered. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**lap.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {LapService} from '../shared/services/lap.service';
import {Lap} from '../shared/model/lap.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lap',
  templateUrl: './lap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lap.component.css']
})
export class LapComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'year', 'lap', 'shortcut flag', 'start place', 'destination place', 'length', 'height difference'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Lap>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;


  constructor(public rest: LapService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.getLaps());
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }


  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  getLaps() {
    this.rest.getLaps().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log('Laps');
      return data;
    });
  }
}
```

**lap.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row "> {{row.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Year Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="year">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Year </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.year}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Lap Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lap">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Lap </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lap}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Shortcut Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="shortcut flag">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Shortcut Flag </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.shortcut_flag}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Start Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="start place">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Start Place </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.start_place}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Destination Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="destination place">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Destination Place </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.destination_place}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Length Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="length">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Length </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.length}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Height Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="height difference">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Height Difference </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.height_difference}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**lap.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LapService {

  private lapUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/lap';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLaps(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.lapUrl, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData));
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res || {}; // If 'res' is null, it returns empty object
  }

}
```

Comment: can you tell us the console errors?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create `new MatTableDataSource()` and then on data receiving pass that data to `dataSource.data` array.

```
 ngOnInit() {
   // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.getLaps());
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(); // create new object
    this.getLaps(); // forgeted this line
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
 }

   getLaps() {
     this.rest.getLaps().subscribe((data: {}) => {
       console.log(data);
       console.log('Laps');
       this.dataSource.data = data; // on data receive populate dataSource.data array
       return data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: In addition I had to call the getLaps() method in the ngOnInit() method and it did the trick for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add this line on `ngOnInit`:

```
 this.getLaps();
```