# mat-table dataSource doesn't work when using REST API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, components

I am unable to put data in a Material Table.

I made a `Block` model with fields like `id`, `date`, etc. `data.service` is where the API call is and the function `getAllBlock()` returns the blocks. I tried it in `app.component.html` and it works.

**document-list.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Block } from '../models/block.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-document-list',
    templateUrl: './document-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./document-list.component.sass']
})
export class DocumentListComponent implements OnInit {
    blocks: Block[];
    //DataSource and columns for DataTable
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['Id', 'Date', 'Data', 'Hash', 'PreviousHash'];
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Block>(this.blocks);

    //Filter (search)
    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        return this.dataService.getAllBlock()
        .subscribe(data => this.blocks = data);
    }
}
```

**document-list.component.html**

```html
<div class="content-table">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <!-- ID Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Date Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Timestamp</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Date}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Data Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Data">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Data</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Data}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Hash Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Hash">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Hash</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Hash}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Previous Hash -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="PreviousHash">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PrevHash</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.PreviousHash}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I don't know how to insert data into the table. What's wrong in what I've done or where is the problem?

Comment: Try with this answer its similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575692/angular-material-mat-table-not-rendering-data-from-rest-api/54576168#54576168

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're dealing with async data so initially `this.blocks` is `undefined`. You need to create the `dataSource` once `this.blocks` is defined which is after you subscribe to `getAllBlock()`. It also doesn't make sense to use `return` here since you just get the data from the `subscribe` method. So just simply call `getAllBlock()` instead.

Here's how your code should look now.

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Block>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getAllBlock().subscribe(data => {
        this.blocks = data
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Block>(this.blocks);
    });
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me solve my problem. Took me hours to figure out. Thanks!